# Adding extension methods to ASP.net repeater's NamingContainer

Tags: asp.net, extension-methods, asprepeater

I'm trying to write an extension method for the asp.net repeater control that would allow me to call the following code in the repeaters template. This is to say that I would like to call my own Eval method on the repeater.

```
<%# UmbracoEval("propertyName") %>
```

I've tried targeting the Repeater control itself as well as the NamingContainer but I get accessibility errors seeing as the Container is protected.

Is this even possible? I've never called extension methods from markup so I'm not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You still need Eval or Bind -  `UmbracoEval(Eval("propertyName"))` or `UmbracoEval(Bind("propertyName"))`.

Both Eval and Bind return an object, so extension method for an object is not a good idea.

However, you can create that `UmbracoEval` in code behind and call it from aspx.

```
protected string UmbracoEval(object eval)
{
    return eval.ToString() + " abc"; // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a method I will have on 40-50 masterpages so I will probably create a helper class. I wanted to stay away from the helper method approach but It looks like it will be the easiest/most doable.

Comment: If it is case, you can create an extension method like [public static string UmbracoEval(this object eval)...]